# Matplotlib Pie Graph with 'All Other Categories"

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created a matplotlib pie chart:

```
df.plot(kind='pie', subplots=True, figsize=(6, 4))
```

My dataframe consists of two columns - Country and Value (% distribution) and has about 25 countries listed. I would like to only plot the top 10 countries by values (by highest %) and within the plot, calculate the remaining countries % value and give it the title of 'All Other Countries'. How do I do this using matplotlib using the .plot function?

```
Country   Value
Albania    4%
Brazil     3%
Denmark    5%
France     10%
Mexico     3%
Nigeria    15%
Spain      4%
U.S.       5%
```

Comment: A general advise: Keep data aggregation and manipulation separate from visualization. So this problem is rather independent on plotting, but would simply be, how to generate a new dataframe which combines several rows into a single one.

Comment: Yes, I do normally do that. I was just wondering if there was a way to do it within the plot function. I  will stick with that plan. Thanks!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

As already stated in the comments, the best way to do this is probably to do the manipulations before plotting. Here's a way how to do it:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

countries = [
        'Albania',
        'Brazil',
        'Denmark',
        'France',
        'Mexico',
        'Nigeria',
        'Spain',
        'Germany',
        'Finland',
    ]

#the full dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {'country': countries, 'value' :np.random.rand(len(countries))},
    ).sort_values('value', ascending = False)

#the top 5
df2 = df[:5].copy()

#others
new_row = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'country' : ['others'],
    'value' : [df['value'][5:].sum()]
})

#combining top 5 with others
df2 = pd.concat([df2, new_row])

#plotting -- for comparison left all countries and right 
#the others combined
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 2, figsize = (9,4))
df.plot(kind = 'pie', y = 'value', labels = df['country'], ax = axes[0])
df2.plot(kind = 'pie', y = 'value', labels = df2['country'], ax = axes[1])
axes[0].set_title('all countries')
axes[1].set_title('top 5')
plt.show()
```

The result looks like this.

[image: result of above code]

Hope this helps.