# How can I add a legend to a Matplotlib pie chart without using proxy artists?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

I'm trying to reduce the size of a pie chart I've made using matplotlib by incorporating a legend. I think the two biggest problems are that I have 18 pie wedges, and using a sample code I incorporated a color map in a funky numpy array I don't quite understand.

I've done some digging and I think I may be able to incorporate a legend still without using proxy artists (I get this error with my code - "Legend does not support)...instances. A proxy artist may be used instead")

I used versions of this solutions to no avail - [How to add a legend to matplotlib pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19852215/how-to-add-a-legend-to-matplotlib-pie-chart) **Ideally I would like my legend to be similar to the one shown here, just with many more labels for the wedges.** I'd like a legend to the bottom left of my chart so that I could reduce its size and turn off the labels around the chart.

I also tried adding commas to `pie_wedge_collection` as was suggested here - [Matplotlib Legends not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983024/matplotlib-legends-not-working)
but that also didn't work...

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# the pie slices are these percentages:
type_list = [1.37, 3.88, 23.72, 1.11, 0.08, 0.13, 6.74, 20.55, 5.2,\
18.46, 0.48, 6.68, 11.6]
slices = type_list
slices = sorted(slices)

len_slice = int(len(slices)/2)
large = slices[:len_slice]
small = slices[len_slice:]

reordered = large[::2] + small[::2] + large[1::2] + small[1::2]

cmap = plt.cm.prism
colors = cmap(np.linspace(0., 1., len(slices)))

labels = 'Civil Rights', 'Criminal Allegation', 'Departmental Violation', 'Domestic', 'Drugs',\
'Falsification', 'Harassment', 'Lack of Service','Non-Investigatory Incident', 'Physical Abuse',\
'Sexual Crime/Misconduct', 'Unprofessional Conduct', 'Verbal Abuse'

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[14,14.76])
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

angle = 164.5 + float(sum(small[::2])) / sum(reordered) * 360

pie_wedge_collection = ax.pie(reordered, colors=colors, labels=labels, shadow=True, labeldistance=1.05, startangle=angle);

for pie_wedge in pie_wedge_collection[0]:
    pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')

ax.set_title("Complaints Against Philadelphia Police \n (2013 - Present) \n Source:OpenDataPhilly.com");

# user warning comes here (with no legend)...  
plt.legend(pie_wedge_collection, labels, loc="best")
plt.axis('equal')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[Here's a link to the resulting pie chart thus far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnFcj.png)

Comment: You could use pandas. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30060628/2454357) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48589225/2454357) for example.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same here as in other answers.

```
wedges, texts = ax.pie(reordered, colors=colors, labels=labels, shadow=True, labeldistance=1.05)

for pie_wedge in wedges:
    pie_wedge.set_edgecolor('white')

plt.legend(wedges, labels, loc="best")
```